# Find unique elements in a container knowing maximum number of occurences

Tags: haskell, filter

I have a sequence whose elements can occur in this sequence only one or two times. I want to get the elements which occur only one time.

I can get them with this function:

```
isUnique :: Eq a => Seq a -> a -> Bool
isUnique xs x = length (DS.filter (== x) xs) == 1
```

but this function does not take into account that the length can be only one or two. It would be more efficient to have a version of `filter` which "stops" whenever two elements are found.

I didn't use Haskell for three or four years, and I lost some knowledge about it. I would appreciate a hint.

---

## EDIT

I have an idea using `(i)find` and `drop`:

```
import           Data.Sequence as DS     (Seq, drop) 
import           Data.Maybe              (isNothing, fromJust)
import           Data.Foldable           (find)
import           Data.Foldable.WithIndex (ifind)

isUnique2 :: Eq a => Seq a -> a -> Bool
isUnique2 xs x = isNothing y 
  where
    (i, _) = fromJust $ ifind (\_ x' -> x' == x) xs
    y = find (== x) (DS.drop i xs)
```

Comment: Just to be clear. Given `['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'c']` you want `['b', 'd']`. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, or even better : **(['b', 'd'], ['a', 'c'])**.

Comment: RE your edit: the `find` function from Data.Foldable returns the element, not the index of the element. So it probably causes a type error if you try to compile that.

Comment: @Noughtmare Ah yes, i have to take the index. I'm correct with the last line. Thanks.

Comment: @Noughtmare That's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to improve your program is to take advantage of laziness. You can do that by converting to a list first and then pattern matching to check if the result is the singleton list or not:

```
import Data.Foldable (toList)

isUnique xs x = 
  case filter (== x) (toList xs) of
    [_] -> True
    _ -> False
```

Due to laziness this will stop filtering as soon as it has found two occurrences of `x`.

But you can improve the worst case complexity by using a `Map a Int` as intermediate data structure (if you may assume that the elements are orderable):

```
filterUnique :: Ord a => DS.Seq a -> DS.Seq a
filterUnique = 
  DS.fromList 
    . Map.keys 
    . Map.filter (== 1) 
    . Map.unionsWith (+) 
    . fmap (\x -> Map.singleton x 1)
```

Your original solution and my improvement above takes O(n ^ 2), but this `Map`-based implementation takes only O(n log n) time in the worst case. Another advantage is that this is already basically in map-reduce form, so it is easy to parallelize.

Comment: Thanks. I need some time to understand. I've edited my question to include a possible solution. Do you think yours is better?

Comment: You wouldn't get much speedup by parallelizing this, I think, because most of the expensive work is in the combining step, the `unions`. Parallel map/reduce works better when the map is expensive and the reduce is relatively cheap.

Comment: @amalloy I guess you might be right about the fact that map reduce is not a good example. But in this case it is possible to parallelize the `unions` function: split the sequence in two and recurse on both in parallel. The only thing that cannot be parallelized is the final combination, but that can be done in linear time. So with sufficiently many threads, this algorithm takes only O(n) time. That is an asymptotic performance improvement!

Comment: I don't see why the final combination would run in linear time. You have `N/K` maps, each of size `K`. Each time you combine two such maps, you insert `K` items, each taking `log(N)` time, making the cost of a single union `K*log(N)`. You do this `N/K` times, yielding a total time of `N*log(N)`.

Comment: @amalloy combining two maps of equal size can be done in linear time. It does not require inserting each element individually.

Comment: @amallo, the recurrence relation is: `T(n) = O(n) + T(n/2)` (there are two branches, but they run in parallel), so [case 3 of the master theorem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/master-theorem/) applies which means `T(n) = O(n)`.